# How to specify "Copy this application onto every target of me" option while deploying using WLST deploy() command?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I want to remove dependency on the location of EAR file while deploying it into WebLogic Server using WLST scripts.

While doing manually we can select the radio button - `Copy this application onto every target for me` in the **Source accessibility** section  of **Install Application Assistant**.

Now the question is: how to achieve the same using WLST `deploy` command?

Thank you,
Chaitanya

Comment: I tried recording option in WL 10 to see what actually happens while deploying EAR. But the recorded file doesnt have anything other than:

startEdit()

activate()

startEdit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this myself!!!

While doing manually I found out in the **Summary section** of the last page of **Install Application Assistant** that `Copy this application to every target for me`
is mentioned against **Staging mode:**

So I checked the WLST manual and found out that `deploy` function accepts `stageMode` parameter and the value of STAGE for stageMode parameter means what I want!

Check **Server Staging Modes** section at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment_api/api_intro.html#1021695

Regards
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

This question is really helps who got stuck in deployments using WLST.
The best practices says use 'nostage' mode deployment so your answer shows the way to use stageMode as solution. Thanks for the sharing.